# WPF animation in datatemplate using VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf, animation, datatemplate, visualstatemanager

It's pretty common issue when you trying to input `VisualStates` for some `DataTemplate`.

The code below works fine, but only if I use a `FrameworkElement`, such as a custom `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl>
    ...namespaces goes here...

 <Grid x:Name="rootgrid">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
                <Storyboard x:Key="Focused">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FFE90B0B"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       </Storyboard>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
              Width="26"
              Height="26"
              Fill="Yellow"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid> 

</UserControl>
```

But when I try to paste the code in `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
   <Grid x:Name="rootgrid">
       ... Code the same as above...
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Then I apply "MyDataTemplate" to my custom element (class, which implements `ContentTemplate` dependency property) and I can't use animation state "Focused" in that case.

Even if I get a grid object called "rootgrid" through VisualTree and use this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(rootgrid,"Focused",true);
```

Nothing happens ... :(

The question is how to use `VisualStates` (animations) implemented in `DataTemplate` for non `FrameworkElement` objects?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?  I was wondering the same thing.  Maybe it's not possible to use visual states with data templates?

Comment: Maybe I fully mistake, but I think that there is no easy way to do this with UIElement such as Ellipse. So you should probably to use classes inherited from Control and see one of tutorials or articles how to work with them. That's all I can advise, sorry.
Actually I don't have much experience in WPF, so maybe someone would told us how to do this best.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is probably too late for the OP, but just for anyone else stumbling across this question:

It is possible to use a `VisualStateManager` in a `DataTemplate`. The key is calling `VisualStateManager.GoToElementState` instead of `VisualStateManager.GoToState` with the `FrameworkElement` that contains the `VisualStateManager`.

By the way, the above XAML doesn't correctly specify the `VisualState` for Focused, this should be changed to:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
        <VisualState Name="Focused>
            <StoryBoard>
```

etc.